# How to solve the error "ERROR 160196: Invalid Topology" when running the split tool

Tags: arcgis-pro, topology, splitting

I am trying to split a multipart features using Split (Analysis) tool. When launching the process I come across the error message "ERROR 160196: Invalid Topology. Failed to execute split".

After some reading (this one for example: https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000006932) , I run the "check geometry" tool. I successfully fixed the identified error (incorrect ring ordering).

I tried again the Split (Analysis) tool but the module still failed. I still get the error "ERROR 160196: Invalid Topology. Failed to execute split". Is there another approach to solve it?

I am using ArcGIS Pro 2.7

Comment: Search on "ERROR 160196", this sounds like a bug in Pro; you should contact Esri Tech Support.

Comment: You have not described your data. Is it a monster multi-part polygon dataset with a billion intricate polygons covering the extent of Asia or just a few houses? I've had topology errors simply because it was too much data.

Comment: @Hornbydd my data is a relatively small multipart polygon (when compared to Asia). It is a landcover of a region in France.